# LaTeX : Package biblatex Warning: citation 'refname' was not found at all in the .bbl, bibliography labels cannot be generated

Tags: latex, bibtex, bibliography

I am straggling to find a fix to my problem. I am trying to add a bibliography reference in my texmaker project. I have tried to chance the `bibtex %` to `bibtex %.aux` but it didn't fix the problem. I also tried to update everything but still no fix. It seems that the code doesn't have problem recognizing the .bib document but i cant detect the bibliography so it doesn't work. Here is my code, source code and my bib format file

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,defernumbers=true,refsection=section]{biblatex}

\title{Example}

\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
Sample text 
\cite{nationaldisord} 



\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]

\end{document}
```

Bibliography:

```
@misc{nationaldisord,
    author       = {National Institute of Neurological Disorders and Stroke},
    title     = {National Institute of Neurological Disorders and Stroke},
    url       = {http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/\~{}uno/abcde.html}
    note = {Accessed 28 Dec 2019}
}
```

Log:

```
LOG FILE :
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (MiKTeX 2.9.7250 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2019.12.28) 29 DEC 2019 11:45
entering extended mode
**./ML_GM.tex
(ML_GM.tex
LaTeX2e <2019-10-01>
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2019/08/27 v1.4j Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\size12.clo"
File: size12.clo 2019/08/27 v1.4j Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count80
\c@section=\count81
\c@subsection=\count82
\c@subsubsection=\count83
\c@paragraph=\count84
\c@subparagraph=\count85
\c@figure=\count86
\c@table=\count87
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/biblatex\biblatex.sty"
Package: biblatex 2019/12/01 v3.14 programmable bibliographies (PK/MW)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/pdftexcmds\pdftexcmds.sty"
Package: pdftexcmds 2019/11/24 v0.31 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/infwarerr\infwarerr.sty"
Package: infwarerr 2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/iftex\iftex.sty"
Package: iftex 2019/11/07 v1.0c TeX engine tests
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/ltxcmds\ltxcmds.sty"
Package: ltxcmds 2019/12/15 v1.24 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/etoolbox\etoolbox.sty"
Package: etoolbox 2019/09/21 v2.5h e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count88
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.sty"
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks14
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/kvoptions\kvoptions.sty"
Package: kvoptions 2019/11/29 v3.13 Key value format for package options (HO)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/kvsetkeys\kvsetkeys.sty"
Package: kvsetkeys 2019/12/15 v1.18 Key value parser (HO)
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/logreq\logreq.sty"
Package: logreq 2010/08/04 v1.0 xml request logger
\lrq@indent=\count89
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/logreq\logreq.def"
File: logreq.def 2010/08/04 v1.0 logreq spec v1.0
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\ifthen.sty"
Package: ifthen 2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/url\url.sty"
\Urlmuskip=\muskip10
Package: url 2013/09/16 ver 3.4 Verb mode for urls, etc.
)
\c@tabx@nest=\count90
\c@listtotal=\count91
\c@listcount=\count92
\c@liststart=\count93
\c@liststop=\count94
\c@citecount=\count95
\c@citetotal=\count96
\c@multicitecount=\count97
\c@multicitetotal=\count98
\c@instcount=\count99
\c@maxnames=\count100
\c@minnames=\count101
\c@maxitems=\count102
\c@minitems=\count103
\c@citecounter=\count104
\c@maxcitecounter=\count105
\c@savedcitecounter=\count106
\c@uniquelist=\count107
\c@uniquename=\count108
\c@refsection=\count109
\c@refsegment=\count110
\c@maxextratitle=\count111
\c@maxextratitleyear=\count112
\c@maxextraname=\count113
\c@maxextradate=\count114
\c@maxextraalpha=\count115
\c@abbrvpenalty=\count116
\c@highnamepenalty=\count117
\c@lownamepenalty=\count118
\c@maxparens=\count119
\c@parenlevel=\count120
\blx@tempcnta=\count121
\blx@tempcntb=\count122
\blx@tempcntc=\count123
\blx@maxsection=\count124
\blx@maxsegment@0=\count125
\blx@notetype=\count126
\blx@parenlevel@text=\count127
\blx@parenlevel@foot=\count128
\blx@sectionciteorder@0=\count129
\blx@entrysetcounter=\count130
\labelnumberwidth=\skip43
\labelalphawidth=\skip44
\biblabelsep=\skip45
\bibitemsep=\skip46
\bibnamesep=\skip47
\bibinitsep=\skip48
\bibparsep=\skip49
\bibhang=\skip50
\blx@bcfin=\read1
\blx@bcfout=\write3
\blx@langwohyphens=\language82
\c@mincomprange=\count131
\c@maxcomprange=\count132
\c@mincompwidth=\count133
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load biblatex default data model...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'blx-dm.def' found.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/biblatex\blx-dm.def"
File: blx-dm.def 2019/12/01 v3.14 biblatex localization (PK/MW)
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load biblatex custom data model...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'biblatex-dm.cfg' not found.
\c@afterword=\count134
\c@savedafterword=\count135
\c@annotator=\count136
\c@savedannotator=\count137
\c@author=\count138
\c@savedauthor=\count139
\c@bookauthor=\count140
\c@savedbookauthor=\count141
\c@commentator=\count142
\c@savedcommentator=\count143
\c@editor=\count144
\c@savededitor=\count145
\c@editora=\count146
\c@savededitora=\count147
\c@editorb=\count148
\c@savededitorb=\count149
\c@editorc=\count150
\c@savededitorc=\count151
\c@foreword=\count152
\c@savedforeword=\count153
\c@holder=\count154
\c@savedholder=\count155
\c@introduction=\count156
\c@savedintroduction=\count157
\c@namea=\count158
\c@savednamea=\count159
\c@nameb=\count160
\c@savednameb=\count161
\c@namec=\count162
\c@savednamec=\count163
\c@translator=\count164
\c@savedtranslator=\count165
\c@shortauthor=\count166
\c@savedshortauthor=\count167
\c@shorteditor=\count168
\c@savedshorteditor=\count169
\c@labelname=\count170
\c@savedlabelname=\count171
\c@institution=\count172
\c@savedinstitution=\count173
\c@lista=\count174
\c@savedlista=\count175
\c@listb=\count176
\c@savedlistb=\count177
\c@listc=\count178
\c@savedlistc=\count179
\c@listd=\count180
\c@savedlistd=\count181
\c@liste=\count182
\c@savedliste=\count183
\c@listf=\count184
\c@savedlistf=\count185
\c@location=\count186
\c@savedlocation=\count187
\c@organization=\count188
\c@savedorganization=\count189
\c@origlocation=\count190
\c@savedoriglocation=\count191
\c@origpublisher=\count192
\c@savedorigpublisher=\count193
\c@publisher=\count194
\c@savedpublisher=\count195
\c@language=\count196
\c@savedlanguage=\count197
\c@origlanguage=\count198
\c@savedoriglanguage=\count199
\c@pageref=\count266
\c@savedpageref=\count267
\shorthandwidth=\skip51
\shortjournalwidth=\skip52
\shortserieswidth=\skip53
\shorttitlewidth=\skip54
\shortauthorwidth=\skip55
\shorteditorwidth=\skip56
\locallabelnumberwidth=\skip57
\locallabelalphawidth=\skip58
\localshorthandwidth=\skip59
\localshortjournalwidth=\skip60
\localshortserieswidth=\skip61
\localshorttitlewidth=\skip62
\localshortauthorwidth=\skip63
\localshorteditorwidth=\skip64
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load compatibility code...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'blx-compat.def' found.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/biblatex\blx-compat.def"
File: blx-compat.def 2019/12/01 v3.14 biblatex compatibility (PK/MW)
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load generic definitions...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'biblatex.def' found.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/biblatex\biblatex.def"
File: biblatex.def 2019/12/01 v3.14 biblatex compatibility (PK/MW)
\c@textcitecount=\count268
\c@textcitetotal=\count269
\c@textcitemaxnames=\count270
\c@biburlbigbreakpenalty=\count271
\c@biburlbreakpenalty=\count272
\c@biburlnumpenalty=\count273
\c@biburlucpenalty=\count274
\c@biburllcpenalty=\count275
\biburlbigskip=\muskip11
\biburlnumskip=\muskip12
\biburlucskip=\muskip13
\biburllcskip=\muskip14
\c@smartand=\count276
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliography style 'numeric'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'numeric.bbx' found.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/biblatex/bbx\numeric.bbx"
File: numeric.bbx 2019/12/01 v3.14 biblatex bibliography style (PK/MW)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliography style 'standard'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'standard.bbx' found.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/biblatex/bbx\standard.bbx"
File: standard.bbx 2019/12/01 v3.14 biblatex bibliography style (PK/MW)
\c@bbx:relatedcount=\count277
\c@bbx:relatedtotal=\count278
))
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load citation style 'numeric'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'numeric.cbx' found.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/biblatex/cbx\numeric.cbx"
File: numeric.cbx 2019/12/01 v3.14 biblatex citation style (PK/MW)
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\cite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\parencite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\footcite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\footcitetext'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\smartcite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\supercite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\textcite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\textcites'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\cites'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\parencites'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\smartcites'.
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load configuration file...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'biblatex.cfg' found.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/biblatex\biblatex.cfg"
File: biblatex.cfg
))
\@quotelevel=\count279
\@quotereset=\count280
(ML_GM.aux)
\openout1 = `ML_GM.aux'.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 8.
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load language 'english'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'english.lbx' found.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/biblatex/lbx\english.lbx"
File: english.lbx 2019/12/01 v3.14 biblatex localization (PK/MW)
)
Package biblatex Info: Input encoding 'utf8' detected.
Package biblatex Info: Automatic encoding selection.
(biblatex) Assuming data encoding 'utf8'.
\openout3 = `ML_GM.bcf'.
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliographic data...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'ML_GM.bbl' found.
(ML_GM.bbl)
Package biblatex Warning: citation 'nationaldisord' was not found at all in the
.bbl, bibliography labels cannot be generated, please correct the citation.
Package biblatex Info: Reference section=0 on input line 8.
Package biblatex Info: Reference segment=0 on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info: External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font) <14.4> on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info: External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font) <7> on input line 9.
LaTeX Warning: No \author given.
\blx@maxsegment@1=\count281
\blx@sectionciteorder@1=\count282
Package biblatex Info: Reference section=1 on input line 11.
Package biblatex Info: Setting label 'refsection:1' on input line 11.
LaTeX Warning: Citation 'nationaldisord' on page 1 undefined on input line 13.
LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 17.
[1
{C:/Users/ferra/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]
(ML_GM.aux)
LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.
Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex) ML_GM
(biblatex) and rerun LaTeX afterwards.
Package logreq Info: Writing requests to 'ML_GM.run.xml'.
\openout1 = `ML_GM.run.xml'.
)
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
7652 strings out of 492451
143937 string characters out of 3129795
590573 words of memory out of 3000000
12010 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
6063 words of font info for 22 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
35i,6n,39p,796b,1118s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
<C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb><C:/Pr
ogram Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr12.pfb><C:/Program Fil
es/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr17.pfb>
Output written on ML_GM.pdf (1 page, 37646 bytes).
PDF statistics:
18 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Thank You

Comment: If you have `backend=biber` you must not use bibtex but biber!

Comment: Unrelated to your problem but there are several errors in your bib entry: a) missing comma after the url b) corporate authors needs at least one additional layer of {} to prevent biblatex to divide it into multiple names c) it makes no sense to have an identical author and title d) simply use ~ in the url, no need to escape it